# Start program with application minimized

Tags: delphi

Is there any way to detect then override the Windows Shortcut param run Minimized?
I want to detect if the shortcut is wanting to start the program minimized then handle the Minimize/maximize/normal sizing myself later.

I have a splash screen that I create using

```
Form_Splash := TForm_Splash.Create(Application);
```

the I create the main form later using

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm_main, Form_main);
```

after the main form is displayed I destroy the form_Splash and at that time I want to minimize/maximize/normal size the form_main based on what the windows shortcut requested.

Thanks for any help.
Steve...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`GetStartupInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call to get the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passed to your process on creation (`TStartupInfo` in Delphi). The `wShowWindow` member contains the desired initial show state.

What is always good to know is:

> For GUI processes, the first time ShowWindow is called, its nCmdShow
>   parameter is ignored wShowWindow specifies the default value. In
>   subsequent calls to ShowWindow, the wShowWindow member is used if the
>   nCmdShow parameter of ShowWindow is set to SW_SHOWDEFAULT.

So for whatever window [`ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is first called, the value specified in the startup info record will be used. This could affect your splash screen.

But in any case - you can use the value from the `STARTUPINFO` to have your main form acting accordingly.

Personally I would hate the application showing me the splash screen when I want it to start minimized. Usually these applications also steal my input focus which drives me mad.

Comment: Thank you Heinrich that really helped. One more question.  Any idea how I can override the StartInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE so it no longer comes up minimized?

Comment: @Steve I'm glad to help! To prevent the window coming up minimized you could check if it receives the `WM_SHOWWINDOW` message and if yes try to intercept it. If this doesn't work you could create a third (dummy) window which will be your new first window. If this is minimized by Windows you just don't care :)

Comment: FYI to prevent the program from minimizing on startup I added the line CmdShow := 1; before the line Application.Initialize; in my project file. I used a 1 instead of the ws_ShowNormal so I didn't have to add another 'uses'. Steve...